# Pipe leak occasionally when washer is running

Tags: plumbing, leak, washer

So this has been a very weird case for a few months.

We have sent at least 6 different plumbers there for over 10 times and nobody could find out the reason.

What happens is sometimes when the washer is running on the main floor a lot of water pours out from ceiling in the basement. But this only happens SOMETIMES.

The plumbers came and tried to recreate the leak but it just didn't happen while they were there. The basement ceiling was opened up so we could clearly see the pipes. One leak was caught on video (when there was no plumber around) and we could see a fair amount of water came down from the pipes.

We showed the video to the plumbers BUT none of them could find any holes or cracks on the pipes!

Anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: are you sure there wasn't anything else, did a toilet overflow from upstairs?

Comment: Sorry if you have had that many professionals on site how do you expect someone on a computer with no photos and only your description to help?

Comment: Have you tried doing some kind of pressure test?

Comment: @depperm there was absolutely nothing else. toilet or bathtub was not used when leak happened. It only happened when washer was running. One plumber believed the bad caulking around the tub was the cause so he redid caulking but it fix the leak

Comment: @EdBeal i do have photos and videos but they only show water come from where the pipes are. I showed the plumbers the photos and videos but they couldn't tell anything from them. I'm trying on internet for help as I believe there must be someone out there who experienced similar issues. It's just none of the plumbers have dealed with something like this. At this point I feel quite hopeless after sending many plumbers there. Every time they charged me hundreds of dollars without fixing it by the way.

Comment: @IronEagle I don't think any of the plumbers did pressure test. Can you please explain a bit what it does? thank you!

Comment: @AbbyFu [This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86177/plumbing-rough-in-pressure-test-psi) talks about it a bit.  It's more commonly done while a house is still being built, I don't know how feasible it is once a house is constructed, but it would definitively answer if you had a leak somewhere and you might be able to find it by listening for hissing air.  This would mostly be for the DWV stack, which is only under pressure when something is draining water.

Comment: You flush a toilet while the washer is draining or the dishwasher is draining and the drain is not large enough or the venting is blocked by one water source and it overflows at the washer running down the pipe would be my guess again your plumber(s) should have thought of this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the washer standpipe overflowing, and not an actual leak? Washers with high-output drain pumps can overwhelm the drain piping, and it happens intermittantly, and especially often with old, steel, undersized (less than 2") piping.